# How to deploy a serverless application to specific / limited Google Cloud regions using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, terraform, google-cloud-run, infrastructure

I have been following [this tutorial](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multi-region-terraform/) to run global services with Google Cloud Run using Terraform.

That is enabled by using a data source to retrieve all Cloud Run regions as a list and deploying in all of them;

```
    data "google_cloud_run_locations" "default" { }
```

Then, deploying the Cloud Run service using `for_each` construct in HCL:

```
    for_each = toset(data.google_cloud_run_locations.default.locations)
```

I want to achieve something similar be able to add specific / limited regions as opposed to deploying in all regions. For example, to a list I declare in `terraform.tfvars`.

I suppose there are slight modifications to be made in case that is possible.

More information:

As per the [official docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-basic), I can specify a location where I want to run my service.

This [link](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multi-region-terraform/) shows how to configure cloud run to deploy to all available regions.

What I want to do is to deploy to more than one region (but not all) with Terraform, e.g.

```
["us-west1", "us-central1", "us-east1"]
```

Is it possible or would I need to change the data source that retrieves all Cloud Run regions?

Comment: We would need more information about the specific regions you want to select as a subset, and also what your variable list would look like.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have edited to provide more Information. I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 2):

The data for `google_cloud_run_locations` does not allow filtering because the API endpoint only supports returning all possible locations. Therefore, we need to do the filtering in Terraform DSL. There is no intrinsic function that is equivalent to a `filter`, `select`, etc. from other languages. Therefore, we need a `for` lambda expression here.

All possible locations are stored in the attribute `data.google_cloud_run_locations.default.locations`, so we would filter on that list with a regular expression. Given the example in the question of limiting to the list `["us-west1", "us-central1", "us-east1"]`:

```
for_each = toset([for location in data.google_cloud_run_locations.default.locations : location if can(regex("us-(?:west|central|east)1", location))])
```

The conditional selects only the locations which match the regular expression because the `can` function returns a `boolean` type for a successful or unsuccessful match. The regular expression can be easily modified for a different subset of locations if necessary.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm going to try that approach and will be sure to come back with feedback

Comment: @scotttheos did you tried the solution that Matt mentioned? Did it worked for you?

Comment: Hello @Vicky, Yes I did. It is a very great approach when dealing with a few specific locations but it didn't match my use case as I wanted to not set locations by regex in main.tf but rather dynamically set a list in terraform.tfvars which as it appears isn't supported currently. 

The regex could be hard to maintain if I'm considering deploying to about 14 new locations.

Comment: Does it have to be Terraform based? Are you familiar with [Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/README.html)? This is a Python package for dynamically injecting variables using templates.